# Vaadin 23 cannot handle @Viewport annotation

Tags: vaadin

I have upgraded a Vaadin 14 app to Vaadin 23.1.3 and now it refuses to start with this error message:

```
Found app shell configuration annotations in non `AppShellConfigurator` classes.
Please create a custom class implementing `AppShellConfigurator` and move the following annotations to it:
    - @Viewport from my.custom.class
```

However, my class does not have this annotation, it only extends an abstract class with this annoation. But I cannot change the abstract class, because it is a third party lib. So is there a way to tell Vaadin to just ignore this annotation and use the one I provided in the AppShellConfigurator class? Or any other way to get this app to start short of ditching the 3rd party library?

Comment: Report the problem to the maintainer and get it fixed.

Comment: No there isn't, your 3rd party library need to get fixed or you going back to vaadin 14. It has still LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problematic class is just an abstract one, You can try creating a custom class with exactly the same structure and name but without the Viewport annotation. Then just import your custom class instead of the one from external package.

For example while using the `AppLayoutRouterLayout` class from com.github.appreciated:app-layout-addon package You could replace its usage with following class:

```
import com.github.appreciated.app.layout.component.applayout.AppLayout;
import com.github.appreciated.app.layout.component.router.AppLayoutRouterLayoutBase;

public abstract class AppLayoutRouterLayout<T extends AppLayout> extends AppLayoutRouterLayoutBase<T> {

}
```